# Why is QTextCharFormat not a MetaType?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get a `QTextCharFormat` out of my `data()` method in Qt.
So I coded my data method in a way that, when the requested data has a `DecorationRole` it returns a `QTextCharFormat` (until now nothing unusual.. I guess)

Problem is that I'm not able to cast back my `QVariant` to a `QTextCharFormat` in my view :(

I'll show you what I tried and what I got as an error:

```
QTextCharFormat charFormat;

charFormat=model->index(i,1).data(Qt::DecorationRole).value<QTextCharFormat>();

setCurrentCharFormat(charFormat);
```

I also tried:

```
charFormat=model->index(1,1).data(Qt::DecorationRole).value();
```

and:

```
 setCurrentCharFormat(qvariant_cast<QTextCharFormat>(model->index(1, 2).data(Qt::DecorationRole))
```

The first snippet is giving me this (I'll drop what result I got from the two latter, I think they are worse solutions)

```
In file included [...]
C:/Qt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/mingw53_32/include/QtCore/qmetatype.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr int qMetaTypeId() [with T = QTextCharFormat]':
C:/Qt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/mingw53_32/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:360:39:   required from 'bool QVariant::canConvert() const [with T = QTextCharFormat]'
C:[...].cpp:29:58:   required from here
C:/Qt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/mingw53_32/include/QtCore/qmetatype.h:1732:5: error: static assertion failed: Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system
     Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(QMetaTypeId2<T>::Defined, "Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system");
```

So I figured that it isn't a metatype, even If this [part of the documentation looked like I could qvariant cast something from GUI.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#a-note-on-gui-types) and that this part is stating that `QTextCharFormat` [isn't in the build in metatype enum](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#details) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
QTextCharFormat textCharFormat;
QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(textCharFormat);
textCharFormat = v.value<QTextCharFormat>();
```

However, as you have tested, `QTextCharFormat` is not declared to the Qt meta type system so you need to add:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QTextCharFormat)
```

Ideally I would placed it a a custom header, which I would use instead of Qt header.:

```
// textcharformat.h
#ifndef TEXTCHARFORMAT_H
#define TEXTCHARFORMAT_H

#include <QTextCharFormat>
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QTextCharFormat)

#endif
```

Now, why it is not already declared as a meta type by Qt, you would have to ask Qt developers.

Comment: I figured I needed to declare it, but as it's part of the lib I had no idea how !
Thanks I'll give it a go ASAP

Comment: I tried It, sadly same error ( Yeah I'm surprized too .. ).
On top on that I don't get what you're trying to say with.
`QTextCharFormat textCharFormat;
QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(textCharFormat);
textCharFormat = v.value<QTextCharFormat>();`
I don't have a `textCharFormat` that is ready to use, I'm in my view and only getting a QVariant from my model.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It does compile now, I forgot to add `#include "textcharformat.h"` in in my view class header, even if it seemed redundant with `#include <QtWidgets/QPlainTextEdit>`  that already includes `QTextCharFormat`.
I'll keep you posted

Comment: `QTextCharFormat textCharFormat; QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(textCharFormat); textCharFormat = v.value<QTextCharFormat>();` code is only here to show you a general way to convert a QTextCharFormat to QVariant and a QVariant to QTextCharFormat.

Comment: There are no redundancy between `#include "textcharformat.h"`  and `#include <QtWidgets/QPlainTextEdit>`. Even if both include `QTextCharFormat`; `textcharformat.h` adds `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and that is the whole point of my answer.

Comment: That's clear now.  
About the include thing, I meant that my view that only aware of the "regular" `QTextCharFormat`, coming from `<QtWidgets/QPlainTextEdit>` so I needed to include `#include "textcharformat.h"` afterwards.

Comment: Now code is running fine but I'm not getting the right `QTextCharFormat` from my model... I gonna looked up why. I'm marking this as the answer because my new issue is beyond the scope of this post. Thanks :)